# How to copy consecutive values to an array

Tags: arrays, numpy, replace, indexing, copy

```
copyto = zeros(10)
what = ones(3)
where = 2
copyto[where:len(what)+where] = what
```

Is there a way to copy all values from a smaller array into a bigger array at a specific position, without providing the upper index?  The way I thought it would work was

```
copyto[where:] = what
```

but this gives me

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At the left and the right hand of the assignment you must have arrays with the same shape so that a one-to-one correspondence between the individual elements exist. In your case the array(view) `copyto[where:]` has 8 elements, while `what` has 3, so your assignment is not well defined. (Or to put it otherwise: there is no unique way to assign three values to eight variables, therefore the assignment is ill defined.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I am looking for a expression that assigns all items from `what` to 'copyto' in a consecutive order at position `where`. very much like what the longer expression does but without the need to specify the upper index.

Comment: But there is no simpler way. As stated above, you have to have the same shape on both sides of the assignment, and therefore you must specify the upper index in your example.

Comment: I post the question, looking for a alternative way. "There is no other way" is not a helpful answer. Apart, the problem is not ill defined as you state (although the given statement is, but it was only given as an example to show what I was looking for).

Comment: Sure, you can dislike it as it does not give you "an alternative way". Alternatively, you could just accept the fact that Python and Numpy were not invented/developed by you and therefore may work differently from how you think about such constructs. You may even try to understand the reasons why it was not done the way you expected it. And this is exactly what my post wanted to be useful for, nothing more.